# Italics using csquotes with foreign language

Tags: typography, csquotes

Using the `csquotes` package and `polyglossia` with French, i want to transform only `\foreignquote{english}{my text is write in english italics with « » typography}` into italics.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,french=guillemets,maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
\sidecapmargin{outer}
\setsidecappos{t}

\usepackage[backend=biber,backref=true, natbib=true, isbn=false, doi=false, url=false, style=authoryear,maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=999, sorting=nyt, refsection=chapter, hyperref]{biblatex}

\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{library.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{bringhurst}

\foreignquote{english}{my text is write in english italics with « » typography}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

For example on Wikipedia, the French citation page says " only use «» " :  Voici « une citation en français », mais « *here is a quotation in English* ».

Update 1 :

Example given by egreg work only for one level of nested quote at this time, and often you can have some citation like this :

```
\foreignquote{english}{my text is write in english italics with « » typography, and a \foreignquote{english}{ nested level of citation like this }  }
```

Give something like this : « my text is write in english italics with « » typography, and a "nested level of citation" like this »

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can exploit the fact that `\em` is a switch:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,french=guillemets,maxlevel=3]{csquotes}

\DeclareQuoteStyle{english}
  {\mkfrenchopenquote{\guillemotleft}\em}
  {\em\mkfrenchclosequote{\guillemotright}}
  {\textquotedblleft\em}
  {\em\textquotedblright}


\begin{document}

Des mots français \foreignquote{english}{with an English quote} suivi
par mots français.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! thanks, that work's for all type of csquote item ?

Comment: @reyman64 I just duplicated the French style, adding `\em` for the text, so it should work as required. Please, do some experiments and report the result as I don't know how you'll be using the command.

Comment: Hum, i test with `foreignblockquote{}` and italics don't work, perhaps because there is some type of recursion in this command ? Documentation says : If it exceeds
the threshold, it will be wrapped in an otherlanguage* environment which is in
turn wrapped in a block quotation environment.

Comment: is there a way to take nested `\foreignquote{english}` with your work, because at this time it don't work :/

Comment: @reyman64 Nested? Please, make a followup question with a proper example.

Comment: I add an example of code of nested citation :)

Comment: @reyman64 It's normal to have different quotes for nested quotations.

Comment: @reyman64 Also, emphasis in an italic context is rendered with roman type. I get the expected result.

Comment: Hum, ok, so it's not possible to have italics in a nested citation , it's a normal behavior ?

Comment: @reyman64 I guess you just need to use `\itshape` instead of `\em` in the code.

Answer (score 4):

How about this? It creates a new (cs-)quote style named `fquotes` and a corresponding command named `\myfquote`. (I don't know if one can define csquote command immediately, however.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareQuoteStyle{fquotes}
  {\em}{}{\em}{}

\newcommand*{\myfquote}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
    \setquotestyle{fquotes}%
    \enquote{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
  bla bla bla \enquote{testing \myfquote{foreign quote}} bla bla bla 
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

I have recently stumbled upon the very same problem but found a simpler and (I think) cleaner solution, as it only uses the features of the loaded packages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Linux Libertine O Italic}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[autopunct,french=guillemets]{csquotes}
%\usepackage[autostyle=true,french=guillemets,maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
\sidecapmargin{outer}
\setsidecappos{t}

\usepackage[backend=biber,backref=true, natbib=true, isbn=false, doi=false, url=false, style=authoryear,maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=999, sorting=nyt, refsection=chapter, hyperref]{biblatex}

\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{library.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{bringhurst}

Essai de texte en français \foreignquote{english}{my text is write in english italics with « » typography \textquote[][]{still quoted in english}}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Basically, you declare `\setotherlanguage{english}` and then you create a new font family for this language, choosing an italic font : `\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Linux Libertine O Italic}`.

Then, you remove at least the `autostyle=true` option when loading the csquotes package. That way, it will fall back to default `autostyle=tryonce`, meaning it will use the main language quotes (in your case french) even if you switch for another language somewhere in your document.

I would also recommend you leave the `french=guillemets` behind, first because you clearly misinterpret [the Wikipedia page you're referring to](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet#Double_ou_triple_niveau_de_citation) and then because once you enter a foreign language you *must* use the typographic conventions of this language (you wouldn't put a non-breaking space before a question mark in a quote in English, would you?), so *in* a quote in English you must use English quotes. So using the package default (`french=quotes`) will be correct both for inner quotes in French or in English.